# Why can I create unique_ptr with decayed array pointer using make_unique?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr

Specifically, I'm wondering why this compiles:

```
#include <memory>
#include "make_unique.hpp"
void foo(const char *s){
   std::unique_ptr<const char*>ptr = std::make_unique<const char*>(s);
}
```

and this does not:

```
#include <memory>
#include "make_unique.hpp"
void foo(const char *s){
   std::unique_ptr<const char*>ptr(s);
}
```

Seems to be working when I write it like in make_unique implementation:

```
#include <memory>
#include "make_unique.hpp"
#include <iostream>
std::unique_ptr<const char*> foo(const char *s){
   /* return std::make_unique<const char*>(s); */
   return std::unique_ptr<const char*>(new decltype(s)(std::forward<decltype(s)>(s)));
}
int main(){
    const char * s = "bar";
    std::unique_ptr<const char*>ptr = foo(s);
    std::cout<<*ptr;

}
```

**EDIT* errors(truncated)**

```
 error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'const char *' to 'std::unique_ptr<const char *>'
   return std::unique_ptr<const char*>(s);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:169:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known
      conversion from 'const char *' to 'pointer' (aka 'const char **') for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
      unique_ptr(pointer __p) noexcept
      ^
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us the actual errors you get, as that might explain the "why".

Comment: I think you are specifying an unintended extra level of indirection.  `std::unique_ptr<X>` is a wrapper for `X*` not for `X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `std::make_unique<T>(args...)` expects to construct a `T` from `args...`.
2. `std::unique_ptr<T>(p)` expects `p` to be an owning value of type `T *`.

Take note that your unique pointer models a `const char **`, not a `const char *`. So in (1) you create a new, dynamically allocated char pointer whose value is copied from `s`, whereas in (2) you're trying to create a unique pointer that takes ownership from something, but you're passing it a constructor argument of the wrong type.

Comment: That helped me wrap my head around it somewhat. Is there a practical difference between std::unique_ptr<T[]> and std::unique_ptr<T*> ?

Comment: @Mikel: They're completely different things. The former holds a pointer to the first element of an array of `T`; the latter points to a dynamically allocated `T*`. That's comparing apples and bears. The real comparison of interest is between `unique_ptr<T>` and `unique_ptr<T[]>`, both of which can be constructed from an owning `T*`.